# Problem with arrayList e session jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a problem with my program.

I have a servlet; in this servlet save the session attribute

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>;
list.add(1);
request.getsession().setAttribute("list",list);
```

Now the attribute is a String and not an ArrayList.
In fact when i try to do:

```
request.getsession().getAttribute(list)
```

is a string and not an Array.

I want an Array.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to cast when you get the attribute from the session like this:

```
 ArrayList<Integer> list = (ArrayList<Integer>)request.getsession().getAttribute("list");
```

And the attributes in the session are stored in a map, that is why the key you used is a String and you have to use a string to retrieve the value.

Comment: @zp26 What is the problem with it?

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to 
  ArrayList<Integer>

Comment: @zp26 Fixed. Also org.life.java - Jigar Joshi had it correct all along.

Comment: @zp26 this is not a problem.. Just change the cast to ArrayList<Integer> list = (ArrayList<Integer>)object and the "Unchecked" will disappear. "The local variable.." that means you are not using the variable along the rest of the code (or sometimes it bugs when you use it inside some conditions, cant remember very well wich ones).

Comment: Sorry but the Unchecked cast don't disappear.

Comment: The unchecked cast is a warning, not an error.  It's telling you that you're casting a non-generic object (`request.getsession().getAttribute("list")`) to a generic object (`ArrayList<Integer>`).  You might be able to get rid of it by adding `<%! @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") %>` at the top of your jsp.

Answer (score 1):

[`session.getAttribute(..)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) returns `Object`

You will have to cast it like

```
List<Integer> list = (List<Integer>)request.getsession().getAttribute("list");
```

Answer (score 1):

As answered in your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606011/problem-with-interaction-servlet-jsp) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369131/problem-with-jsp-servlet-page), just access it by EL in JSP.

```
${list}
```

If you want to iterate over it, use JSTL `c:forEach`:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
    ${item}<br />
</c:forEach>
```

#### See also:

- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)